# Online db for Android App

Tags: android, database

I try Firebase and it works great but if I want to try to use another DB to host my files so user can access it, is there a db that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Use mlab.com to host NO SQL ( Not only SQL)  database.
If you want to use RDBMS use Heroku.